# POS Thermal printer integration in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, epson

I have an angular app developed in angular version 5. I need to integrate EPSON TM-T82. pos thermal printer for printing purpose. I searched for packages in npm and doesn't anyone. Is any javascript integration available for that? I tried the Javascript SDK provided by EPSON, but it communicates only with an intelligent printer ie TM-T82i versions.

Comment: There are resources I've found for `TM-T82` in about 15 seconds. Such as [this one](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=4768&scat=57&pcat=3), or [this](https://www.epson.eu/viewcon/corporatesite/cms/index/11469) and [api reference](http://www.seathost.net/EPSONPrinting/ePOS_SDK_for_JavaScript_um_en_revA.pdf) and many more. However please note that questions that ask for libraries are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: its only works with intelligent printers,not supported for TM-T82.The javascript sdk they provided does not have the capablity to communicate with TM-T82.

Comment: For javascript SDK.The TM-T82 is not available in the  applicable products list of javascript SDK. 4. ePOS-Print SDK for JavaScript Version 5.0.0Ea 
Web Browser Version: 
- Windows Internet Explorer 9 or later 
- Mozilla Firefox 3.6 or later 
- Google Chrome 7 or later 
- Safari in iOS 4.0 or later 
- Standard browser in Android 2.2 or later 
Applicable Products: 
TM-T88IV, TM-T88V, TM-T70, TM-T70II, TM-T90, TM-L90, TM-P20, TM-P60II, TM-P80, TM-U220, TM-m10, TM-m30 
Interface: Wireless LAN (UB-R04)

Comment: I found a solution by using QZ tray.